# Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: java.io.IOException(Ubuntu)

Tags: apache-drill, pydrill

I am trying to start the Apache-drill but I am facing this error continuesley. How can I figure it out?

```
Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8047 (state=,code=0)
```

I tried to edit `drill-override.conf` file like below. I am getting the same error again!

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

#  This file tells Drill to consider this module when class path scanning.
#  This file can also include any supplementary configuration information.
#  This file is in HOCON format, see https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md for more information.

# See 'drill-override-example.conf' for example configurations

drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",
  zk.connect: "localhost:8048"
}
```

Also, you can see the `netstat` command result:

```
~$ netstat -tlnp | grep 8047
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6      11      0 :::8047                 :::*                    LISTEN      12801/java


:~$ netstat -tlnp | grep 8048
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Amin,
I think you need explicitly set what port Drill is using in your config.  The config argument is `drill.exec.http.port`.

Take a look at the docs here: https://drill.apache.org/docs/ports-used-by-drill/ and here: https://drill.apache.org/docs/start-up-options/ for more details on how to set up the config.

Comment: I have exploited help from some friends and I solved it by putting `http.port: 8048` instead of `zk.connect: "localhost:8048"`. BTW, thank you for your response